# Problem with usable screen height in landscape - iOs Safari

Tags: html, css, ios, safari

need some help with a website I'm working on.
Portrait mode on Android looks like this:

[image: portrait Android]

Now, landscape, no css change:

[image: landscape Android]

No problem whatsoever. Follow me to the next screenshot illustrating what happens on iOs Safari/Chrome in portrait mode. Everything fine:

[image: portrait iOs]

Landscape mode goes to "fullscreen" since it's an SE so I figured the screen, being quite small, goes full screen and that still looks fine.

[image: landscape iOs]

I can scroll through the content no problem. However, when I click a link to go to another page this happens:

[image: broken landscape iOs]

The behavior of the page is quite simple: the scrollable content is inside a div which is the rounded one which mustn't move during scrolling. What happens is that the rounded div is set to be 100% height of the screen and when top and bottom navbars appear on iOs, the rounded div won't change its height to adapt to the usable screen part.

body css is as following:

```
body {
margin: 0; 
height: 100%; 
overflow: hidden; 
-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; }
```

while rounded corners div is managed like this:

```
.rcorners {
position: absolute;
margin-top:15px;
margin-bottom:15px;
margin-left:15px;
margin-right:15px;
top: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%-20px;
height: 100%-20px;
background-color: white;
border-radius: 10px;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 6px 2px #C0C0C0;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 6px 2px #C0C0C0;
box-shadow: 0 0 6px 2px #C0C0C0;
overflow:hidden; }
```

Any ideas on how to make the height right everytime the usable screen size changes?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

So sadly iOS has been notorious for this type of stuff for what seems years. First it was the top address bar, and now it is the browser menu. So you have a couple options. YOu can set a media query for landscape and shorten the height of that container and just have it scroll if you need. Could probably drop font-size too. Or there are a couple options in this article that might help.

You could also try 100vh instead as well. As that will make it the full height of the available viewport which I have seen at times act the way I needed it to vs 100% height.

https://www.eventbrite.com/engineering/mobile-safari-why/

Comment: Thank you for the prompt answer!
I should have specified that I would like to keep the same behavior as in portrait mode. 

Gave the 100vh a show to no avail, unfortunately :( the page still has the same look I showed earlier.

Shortening the container would make this look strange, especially because of the fact that on other iPhones like XS Max there is only a top navigation bar while on Android I would have a shorter container than the full height. I would get inconsistent results. On SE it may look good while on XS Max and Android it would look bad.

Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: No nothing you are missing at all. I have ran into a few of these similar issues with iOS and at times android as well. These might help. I would just get more finite with a media query and target the exact resolutions of the SE to make it look right while not affecting the other OSs or sizes http://stephen.io/mediaqueries/iphonex/

The web is a very fluid medium and while I would love to make something and know it will respond perfectly on all devices with one set of CSS that just isn't reality. 

So in cases like yours I just set a very specific media query.

Comment: Thing is, I would need to keep the landscape view with a consistent usable height, as it happens in portrait mode. I mean: always visible top and bottom navigation bars or always "fullscreen". From what I could understand, in my situation Safari will make use of 100% (even when using 100vh) height when in landscape view (without considering navigation bars) hence the correct view when going to landscape mode from portrait.

Comment: Alright just checked your second comment but there's still a problem. The usable height in landscape view keeps changing on SE. If I go to landscape from portrait it will go fullscreen and then if I click a link those obnoxious bars will appear, making every "right" height setting be useless. I know my situation is quite strange and peculiar to say the least cause I haven't gone any classic route by using such a particular way of displaying content. 
Anyway, sorry to bother you.

Comment: You're not a bother by any means. I sadly do not have an SE on hand especially the brand new one so I can't replicate what is exactly happening sadly. If it takes too long to get perfect, I usually just make the sacrifice needed for it to be usable on that device.

Comment: If you can shoot me a link to your live code I would be more than happy to try and help you find a solution that works for you.

Comment: Yeah I'm probably scratching my head over something that is not as important as I think.
To compare the SE situation with something more recent and with a way larger screen, this is a test on an actual iPhone XS Max: 

https://imgur.com/a/JWWMkcj

As you can see, the view won't go fullscreen when in landscape so I can use a media query to target this specific device (screen size) and make the container fit using a shorter height. That way, I would be able to scroll the content inside the div without the risk of the view going fullscreen.

Comment: Do you know which iOs devices will go fullscreen when going to landscape mode? I think the SE (2016 version) is set that way because of the small screen but I suspect (hope not) it happens on smaller that xs Max screen like the ones found on iPhone 7/8/new SE. I don't have a 4.7 inch iPhone to test this out, unfortunately.

Comment: I have no idea as I only have used iOS devices while QAing websites and not in daily use so I would not know off hand. There may be a way code wise to disable that though possibly!

Comment: Hey just read your last comment. You can check the website which is:

risewell.it

Just removed password-protection. Thank you very much!

Comment: Okay so seeing it visually I can see the issue. The issue is that you have the height of your box set to 100% which will fill up based on the body which is 100%(which is correct) but means that your corners div will only fill 100% of the height which is short on landscape.

So if you want to show all the content in your box on landscape I would highly suggest using the min-height property on landscape!

Comment: As a base I think I tried 500px and it fit everything including the button.

Comment: Yeah just used 500px! Can't believe we thought the exact same value! Seems to work smooth even if it won't retain the div position as in portrait and it simply scrolls to the bottom but who cares. Now it's usable, at least. Maybe it's even better this way since it will make use of the whole height!
Great minds think alike, I guess, but you sir, have a greater mind than me cause you solved the issue!

Excuse my enthusiasm but you can imagine what it feels to make something work after long hours of trial-and-error game!

Comment: What you can do is only apply at min height on landscape orientation if you want to keep portrait how it is! Oh it is a great feeling hah. Enjoy it.

Comment: Yeah done that with media query for landscape. Works fine.

Comment: Cheers! Have a nice day amazing stranger!